# Tables in tabsetPanel not loading? R (Flexdashboard/Shiny)

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

This is a problem I can't seem to solve and I'm not sure why its happening.

My goal is to use the tabBox to put various tables in a single "flexdashboard area" and using {.tabset} is not an option. But it seems that when I start using tabPanels - only the first panel will generate my DT table and the second will not. The headers of the table are generating but I can't figure our why the actual data will not.

I'll be grateful for any help.

Here is what I see: Tab 1 is fine
[image]

Tab 2 does not load at all but the columns do
[image]

Here is my code

````
---
title: "Example Demo Dash"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny 
---


# Tab 1

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(readr)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(rsconnect)
require(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
require(plotly)
```

Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tab 1 Graph

# Tab 2

Column {data-width=450}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Cars Tab 1  

```{r}


cars <- datatable(mtcars,
          rownames = FALSE,
          options = list(
            dom = 't',
            paging = FALSE,
            info = FALSE,
            scrollY = FALSE,
            sort = FALSE
            
      )
) 


iris <- datatable(mtcars,
          rownames = FALSE,
          options = list(
            dom = 't',
            paging = FALSE,
            info = FALSE,
            scrollY = FALSE,
            sort = FALSE
            
      )
) 
```

```{r}
tabsetPanel(
       #Dec 2020
       tabPanel("Cars 1", cars), 
       #Jan 2021
       tabPanel("Iris", iris))
```


### Col 2 Row 2


Column {data-width=200}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 1

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 1

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 3

### Tab 2 Col 2 Graph 3

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Col 3 graph 1

### Col 3 graph 2

# tab 3
````

Edit:Added package and R info

```
> packageVersion('flexdashboard')
[1] ‘0.5.2’
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.3                         
year           2020                        
month          02                          
day            29                          
svn rev        77875                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock        
>
```

Comment: It is working with `packageVersion('flexdashboard')#
[1] ‘0.5.2’`

Comment: Okay, should I delete all my packages and just redownload them?

Comment: Are you using the latest R version?

Comment: @akrun I added my version of R and the package version

Comment: I am using `R 4.0.3`.  May be that your old version of R and some of the package versions that work on it have an impact

Comment: @akrun unfortunately even after updating my R version I still get the error.